# Trying to add a ribbon to the edit form as the first button before save?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, ribbon, custom-actions

I'm trying to add a button here:

[image]

```
 <CustomAction
      Id="SaveAndCheckIn.EditForm"
      Location="CommandUI.Ribbon.EditForm"
      Rights="EditListItems">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition
        Location="Ribbon.DocLibListForm.Edit.Commit">
          <Button
          Id="Ribbon.ListForm.Edit.Manage.Controls.SaveAndCheckIn"
          Alt="Save and Check In the document."
          LabelText="Save and Check In"
          Image16by16="/_layouts/15/1033/images/formatmap16x16.png?rev=40"
          Image32by32="/_layouts/15/1033/images/formatmap32x32.png?rev=40"
          Command="SaveAndCheckIn"
          Sequence="1"
          TemplateAlias="o1"
          ToolTipTitle="Save and Check In"
          ToolTipDescription="Save and Check In the document."/>
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler
        Command="SaveAndCheckIn"
        CommandAction=""
        EnabledScript=""/>
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<CustomAction
Id="JustMyButton"
RegistrationType= "List"
RegistrationId= "101"
Location= "CommandUI.Ribbon.EditForm"
Sequence= "100"
Title= "Just My Button" >
<CommandUIExtension>
  <CommandUIDefinitions>

    <CommandUIDefinition
        Location="Ribbon.DocLibListForm.Edit.Commit.Controls._children">
      <Button 
         Id="CustomActionDemo.DisplayFormAction"
         Command="Command.CustomActionDemo.DisplayFormAction"
         LabelText="My Button"
         Sequence="1"
         Description="Just My Button"
         Image32by32="_layouts/Images/Custom_Settings/icon_32x32.png"
         Image16by16="_layouts/Images/Custom_Settings/icon_16x16.png"
         Alt="Just My Button"
         TemplateAlias="o1" />
    </CommandUIDefinition>
  </CommandUIDefinitions>
  <CommandUIHandlers>

    <CommandUIHandler
            Command="Command.CustomActionDemo.DisplayFormAction"
            CommandAction="javascript:alert('Hi!');" />
  </CommandUIHandlers>

</CommandUIExtension>
```

Screenshot of result:

[image]

Best regards,

Lee Liu

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add a button to the first position of the Commit group by using Sequence="0" - but I was doing it through SharePoint Designer. Should be the same logic though.

Comment: Is the xml correct, just the sequence needs updating?